# How do I align these TextViews in Android activity_main.xml with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am going through this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

and I'm looking at this code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context="com.santiapps.androidxmlweatherparsing.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="@string/country"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/temperature"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/humidity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/pressure"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:onClick="open"
        android:text="@string/weather" />

</FrameLayout>
```

but it ends up in overlapping fields.

[image: Overlapping Textviews]

How do I fix this?  Android Studio 0.4.3 always creates projects with fragments and most tutorials don't use all that boilerplate code.
Is there any way to turn OFF that feature such that I always get JUST the activity_main.xml and no fragment_main.xml?

Comment: Use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`

Comment: That just jumbles up everything on the far right.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using FrameLayout?

Comment: Got it! Android Studio keeps giving me these fragment boilerplate codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to do what you want to achieve,

1. Use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)
   In this case you need to use LinearLayout for each row.
2. Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)
   You can add rule for each item in the relative layout and tell them like A widget is below B, C is at the very right.
3. You can use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html) which is a table (I would recommend this one for your case).

   ```
   TableLayout
       TableRow
          TextView
          EditText
       TableRow

       TableRow
          TextView
          EditText
       TableRow
   TableLayout
   ```